# Send metadata in WhatsApp Cloud Api

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

Somehow, in order to send a response to the client, I must be able to pass the user's id as metadata or parameter, for example: The reservation request is sent to a restaurant, after that, the restaurant confirms the reservation, in the Confirmation A WhatsApp is sent to the user to inform him that his reservation is confirmed.

For it:

1. WhatsApp with restaurant id metadata to confirm.
2. Whatsapp with the confirmation to the user (I must know the id of the
   restaurant)

In the object returned by WhatsApp I have a context, however I can't find any method to get the information from the context.

I want to send the object:

```
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "52" + recipient,
    "metadata":{
        "idUser": 60,
        "idBranch": 76
    },
    "type": "template",
```

and retrieve the context to know the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, WhatsApp Business API does not have any option to pass metadata in the send message API,

The real approach is you need to store that message-id in your database, whenever you receive webhook object, match that object's message-id in the stored message-id from the database, and do whatever further actions.